# what is <embed id="coba-object" type="application/coba" />

Tags: html, firebug, embed

I find

`<embed id="coba-object" type="application/coba"` ,

what is application/coba ? and i try to debug it using firebug, but it seems firebug could not handle it. what is used to generate the html ?
if you can provide a tool to debug it , it would be helpful, thanks !

Comment: It's not possible for any browser dev tool to debug embedded objects. Question is, why do you want to debug something you don't know what it is? Inside the [Net panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) you can at least see the (probably binary) contents of the requested object.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find this tag from [the offical website of Chinese Railway](http://www.12306.cn/mormhweb/)?

In fact,it is “China Online Banking Assistant” Pulgin in your browser.It's used to make your Firefox (or other modern browser?) support online purchasing operation,which was IE-only in the past.And it's installed on Firefox of Chinese Edition by default.

The source code is [here](https://github.com/MozillaOnline/COBA).